# Getting warnings during installation of a package on solaris

Tags: installation, solaris

I am getting warnings during installation of my package on Solaris.

```
WARNING: setting mode of `</opt/aaa/bbb/ccc>` to default mode (755)
WARNING: setting mode of `</opt/aaa/bbb/ccc/bin>` to default mode (755)
WARNING: setting mode of `</opt/aaa/bbb/ccc/inc>` to default mode (755)
WARNING: setting mode of `</opt/aaa/bbb/ccc/lib>` to default mode (755)
```

Why these warnings are coming during installation?
If that is standard Solaris behaviour, is there a possible way to suppress these warning messages during installation process.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely due to an inconsistency between these four directories permission on disk and defined in the package. If you have created these directories by hand, you made a mistake as these directories should be created during the pkgadd process. Otherwise, contact the builders of the packages sharing these directories to understand why they have set different permissions.